# Align image in a column with text in another column

Tags: tables, graphics, align, margins

I'm trying to align the image in a column with the text in another column in a tabular environment.

I found out how to get the height of the text and size the image accordingly. Then I raise the image with `raisebox`.

But margins remain both below the text and above the image.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\mytable}{
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        A1 & B1 \\
        A2 & B2 \\
        A3 & B3
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mytableh}
\setlength{\mytableh}{\totalheightof{\mytable}}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
    \raisebox{-0.5\mytableh}{\includegraphics[height=\mytableh]{example-image-a}}
    & \mytable \\
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can avoid the space above the image if you use the adjustbox package to position it vertically. As for the space below `A3`, that's part of your table: https://pastebin.com/yLuDY5Yi

Comment: What's wrong with `\raisebox{-0.5\mytableh}`?

Comment: The space you get above your image :)

Comment: But if the bottom of the image is positioned at mid line, by lowering the image by half its height the bottom of the image should be positioned at the bottom of the table, and since the image's height equals the table's height, there should be no space above the image. Why there is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. Using the `[b]` option to the `{tabular}` environment aligns the table to the baseline instead of centring it around the math axis. Since alignment on the baseline is also the default of `\includegraphics`, you don't need to shift anything vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{calc} % not really needed here

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{l l}
        A1 & B1 \\
        A2 & B2 \\
        A3 & B3
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mytableh}
\settoheight{\mytableh}{\mytable}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
\includegraphics[height=\mytableh]{example-image-a}
    & \mytable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They key to your answer seems to be the `[b]` after the table on the right. Can you detail what it does and why it is needed?

Comment: @robertspierre See edit.

Comment: @robertspierre Another problem is that with `\totalheightof` you are adding both height *and* depth of the table: that's why your image is scaled largen than you want it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer